# Font looks broken in Illustrator

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I designed a 3.25x2.25 inch card in CMYK using **Helvetica Neue** font with **450 dpi** in photoshop. Then I opened it in illustrator to save it as a .ai in order to print it. But the main problem is in the .psd file the font looks OK but in illustrator it looks the fonts are broken (I can see the pixels). Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I don't want to change the design or font. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the design on the rest of the card pixelated, or is it just the text?

Comment: just font @anyaMairead

Comment: PS uses pixels, while .ai is a vector image. Can't you remove the text in PS and just add in again in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator uses "hinting" when displaying fonts. Helvetica Neue is missing "hinting" specifications usually included inside of the font. You can prevent Illustrator from trying to display the missing "hinting", which is what is messing up the display, by going to the "Type" "Character" panel and selecting "crisp" or "strong" in the bottom right dropdown. This fixed Helvetica Neue's awful Illustrator rendering for me.